# Cannot access parse dashboard

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I need API keys for my application from my parse dashboard but unfortunately i cannot access the dashboard.(I also tried "I don't have a parse account" button but that didn't help. It redirected me to FAQs)

Whenever I login through either github or google I am being redirected to parse's homepage(as in image 2) instead of going to the dashboard.

[image]

[image]

I read the FAQs where it said "You don't need to sign up for parse now." which lead me nowhere. I also checked youtube videos/tutorials, but that didn't help too. I googled it a lot and nothing seem to work. Is anyone else facing this same problem? Please suggest a alternative way or perhaps a fix here.

Comment: AFAIK, parse is no longer available as a service. So no API keys for you. You can only setup parse if you can host it yourself.

Comment: *Parse will be fully retired after a year-long period ending on January 28, 2017*... Trying to squeeze in that last two months are you?

Comment: Damn old youtube tutorials :( . I've been trying this for 3 days. Thanks for letting me know that.

Comment: Yeah. Most people who don't have any ties to Parse have moved to Firebase.

Comment: @cricket_007 I'll be among those 'most people' too now. Moving to firebase!